# insert updated row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

Icurrently have in my database (SQL server 2005 Express) 2 tables, tblDepartment and tblDepartmentcola. The difference between the two is that "cola" has an additional boolean field. For reasons beyond the scope of this question, i need to insert any changes made to tblDepartment in tblDepartmentcola. For that i need to use a trigger.

After reading some stuff, i got the impression that a temporary "updated" table does not exist? is this right?. If so, how could i select the "updated" row?, i have made triggers in the past making selects from "updated" and "Deleted" tables, but this one does not work. any idea why?

```
CREATE TRIGGER items_ ON [tblDepartment] FOR Update AS
INSERT INTO [tblDepartmentcola]
SELECT ...

go
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no `updated` table in Sql server, only [`inserted` and `deleted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

```
CREATE TRIGGER items_ ON [tblDepartment] after Update AS
begin
    INSERT INTO [tblDepartmentcola]
    SELECT * from inserted
end
```

Comment: old data will be in `deleted` table, new data will be in `inserted` table. If you, for example, have row in tblDepartment like `(col1 = 3, id = 4)` and do `update tblDepartment set col1 = 4 where id = 2`, you have 1 row in `inserted` table `(col1 = 4, id = 2)` and one row in `deleted` table `(col1 = 3, id = 2)`. Notice that inserted and deleted are tables so they could have more than one row

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the records that were updated to insert into a different table you can query the INSERTED table within a trigger when the primary key exists within the DELETED table.

```
INSERT INTO TrackUpdatesTable ( PrimaryFieldId, Field1, Field2, Field3 )
SELECT I.PrimaryFieldId, I.Field1, I.Field2, I.Field3
FROM INSERTED I
JOIN DELETED D ON D.PrimaryFieldId = I.PrimaryFieldId
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TrackUpdatesTable ( PrimaryFieldId, Field1, Field2, Field3 )
SELECT I.PrimaryFieldId, I.Field1, I.Field2, I.Field3
FROM INSERTED I
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM DELETED WHERE PrimaryFieldId = I.PrimaryFieldId )
```

Hope this helps.